# How to capture high quality views of Google Map layer in iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, layer, capture, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to capture a Google Map layer, but I feel the captured image is low quality.

Part of my code is below:

```
// capture the map view(mView)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mView.bounds.size);
[mView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// set the image to myView background image
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myView.frame.size, NO, 0);
[newImage drawInRect:myView.bounds];
UIImage *breakImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:breakImage];
```

The result upper view are captured. The below view is a native Google Map view.

[image: Two Google maps views of Sydney]

How can I get high-quality Google Map view in iOS?

I'm using Google Maps SDK v1.8.1.

Are there any methods like Android's `googleMap.snapshot` callback method in iOS?

Comment: Use [`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) instate of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` to set the correct scale in capturing your view. And set the scale correctly in creating the background image: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myView.frame.size, NO, [UISreen mainScreen].scale);`

Comment: Good! I am glad on your answer. The Method is Ok. Thanks for your response,rckoenes. :)